# How to route traffic from specific IPs/network interface into a commercial VPN wireguard interface?

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, wireguard

I am trying to acheive a setup where I have a Tailscale network of my devices that can route to a VPS on my Tailscale network which is an [exit node](https://tailscale.com/kb/1103/exit-nodes/), but the exit node can then forward the relevant traffic through a ProtonVPN wireguard tunnel. The main motivation for this is that my Android client can only have one 'Always-On' VPN connection at once which requires me to choose between *either* being connected to Tailscale or ProtonVPN.

At the same time I want to make sure that traffic that is meant to 'terminate' at the exit node (for example SSH to the Tailscale IP on the VPS) isn't forwarded to the upstream VPN. For those unfamiliar with Tailscale, it provides a network interface called `tailscale0` with an IP in the [100.64.0.0/10 range to a device](https://tailscale.com/kb/1015/100.x-addresses/). Additionally, I have several Docker containers on the VPS host that expose web services over HTTP/HTTPS on the public internet which I want to remain accessible.

Below is a diagram that summarises my desired setup (along with network interfaces on the VPS):
[image: Desired Tailnet,VPS and VPN setup]

On the VPS exit node I have enabled IP forwading by setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1`. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with ufw enabled allowing ports 80, 443 and SSH.

The wireguard config provided by ProtonVPN looks like so:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <REDACTED>
Address = 10.2.0.2/32
DNS = 10.2.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = <REDACTED>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <PROTON VPN SERVER>:51820
```

I have put this config in `/etc/wireguard/wgpvpn0.conf` but when I run `wg-quick up wgpvpn0`, I can no longer SSH into the VPS (via public internet interface or Tailscale interface) and all my services hosted on port 80/443 exposed over the public interface are no longer accessible. I presume this is due to `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` which makes this `wgpvpn0` interface the default gateway for all traffic.

I think the solution is to use `PreUp/PostDown` in the wireguard config to add some firewall/routing rules however I am not sure what to add due to unfamiliarity with iptables. I think the rules I need are:

- Any traffic which has an **end destination** in the 100.64.0.0/10 range should be managed by the Tailscale network interface.
- Any traffic with an **end destination** of the Tailscale exit node IP should be dealt with by the exit node. I suspect that rule above would deal with this through the Tailscale interface.
- Any traffic that has an **end destination** of the public IP of the VPS should be dealt with by the VPS (e.g. received by `ens3` interface and handled by the reverse proxy running on my VPS).
- Any traffic that is forwarded from my Tailscale network (which means is recieved by the Tailscale interface) to the VPS exit node, but has an **end destination** of the public internet should be routed through the ProtonVPN wireguard interface. Responses in the opposite direction should flow accordingly too. (e.g., login request to google.com Android client via Tailscale network -> VPS on tailscale network -> ProtonVPN tunnel on VPS -> login reponse on Google server via internet -> ProtonVPN tunnel on VPS -> VPS on tailscale network -> Android client on Tailscale network)
- Any traffic originating from the VPS should use the ProtonVPN tunnel (what 0.0.0.0/0 does now).

Can anyone help?